# How do I fix the grid-gap being of different size in my calculator?

Tags: css, css-grid

So I'm making a basic calculator using css grid for the buttons. However, I can´t get my head around why the grid gap seems different, causing what looks like a bigger gap in the center and beneath the top row. Why is this? If I do "grid-gap:0" there is no grid-gap whatsoever. Thanks in advance!

[image: calculator]

```
body {
    background:#1f3535;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.container{
    background:#2f4f4f;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    max-width:500px;
    height:100vh;
}

.top {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    height:30%;
}

h1 {margin:0;}

#heading {opacity:0}


.bottom {
    height:70%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:1px
}

button{border:none;}

.operator {background:#d0d0d0;}

#equals {background:#F78865;grid-column:1/5}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a rendering artifact due to your gap not being a multiple of the pixel density.